# How do I output the last matrix block?

Tags: templating, matrix

I am pretty new to craft (just came from EE) and trying to output the last entry from a matrix field in my template:

```
{% for block in entry.gallery.last() %}
    {% set image = block.image.first() %}
    <img class="lazy" src="{{ siteUrl }}img/assets/loader.gif" data-src="{{ image.getUrl('galleryThumb') }}" data-src-retina="{{ image.getUrl('galleryThumbRetina') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

So this isn't working as I thought, i've done some snooping but have had no luck, any ideas?

Thanks
-Graham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but this should work.

You can get the number of matrix blocks in the matrix field by using the Twig length filter like this ([see Matrix documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields) - scroll to the end):

```
{% set numberOfBlocks = entry.gallery | length %}
```

You should then be able to get the last block by directly referencing it like this (since the array of matrix blocks is zero-based):

```
{% set lastBlock = entry.gallery[numberOfBlocks - 1] %}
```

Now you have the last block, accessing the image field should work as you had in your original code:

```
{% set image = lastBlock.image.first() %}
<img class="lazy" src="{{ siteUrl }}img/assets/loader.gif" data-src="{{ image.getUrl('galleryThumb') }}" data-src-retina="{{ image.getUrl('galleryThumbRetina') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
```

Comment: Excellent work Steve! I am exceptionally pleased with this answer due to the removal of the for loop, much cleaner.

Comment: To be fair, Alec's answer is better than mine. I had forgotten about Twig's `last` filter!

Answer (score 5):

Twig comes with a `last` filter which you should be able to use, so with your `entry.gallery`  you can do:

```
{% set lastBlock = entry.gallery|last %}
```

Which will return the last element in the sequence, there's more info in the twig docs:

> The last filter returns the last "element" of a sequence, a mapping, or a string:

[Twig last filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/last.html)